# Switch to new screen when one of the ObjectChoiceField is selected in black berry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Can any one tell me how to switch to another screen when one of ObjectChoiceField is selected.

Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

```
final class HelloWorldScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
        ObjectChoiceField choice=null;
        public HelloWorldScreen()
        {
                super();
                String choicestrs[] = {"Opt 1", "Opt 2", "Opt 3"};
                choice = new ObjectChoiceField("Object Choice Field: ", choicestrs, 0);
                choice.setChangeListener(this);
            add(choice);
    }
    public void openAnotherForm(){
        AnotherForm newScreen = new AnotherForm();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(newScreen);
    }
    public void fieldChanged(Field arg0, int arg1) {
        openAnotherForm();

    }
}
class AnotherForm extends MainScreen
{
public AnotherForm()
{
        super();
        add(new LabelField("Another Form"));
}
}
```

Comment: In the above code switches to another screen when opt 3 is selected.i require any option.

Comment: Hmm, then remove the if-clause in fieldChanged and just call openAnotherForm().